# Wake on LAN stopped working 19.04

Tags: power-management, wakeonlan

Wake-on-LAN was working in 19.04 just fine, then I left my computer on full time for a few weeks, now WOL no longer works to wake up my desktop from suspend mode.

The `sudo ethtool enp2s0 |grep Wake` command shows:

```
Supports Wake-on: pg
Wake-on: g
```

One thing I noticed though is that it might be related to the power state. Before, when my computer would suspend, the power light would slow blink blue. Now, the power light is off in suspend mode. Running `cat /sys/power/mem_sleep` returns `s2idle [deep]`.  When I went through a bunch of things to set it to `[s2idle] deep`, all it did was make it so my computer didn't really go to sleep or WOL.

I have tried older kernel (5.0.0-15 through 5.0.0-20 and 4.14.134) with no success.

I tried editing the .yaml file in /etc/netplan as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144043/wake-on-lan-not-working-1in-new-19-04) to this:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
#  renderer: NetworkManager
  renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
       enp2s0:
          match:
            macaddress: 90:2b:34:ad:b5:f4
          dhcp4: true
          wakeonlan: true
```

I tried this command to show magic packets received

```
sudo ngrep '\xff{6}(.{6})\1{15}' -x port 9
```

and got this:

```
interface: enp2s0 (192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0)
filter: ( port 9 ) and ((ip || ip6) || (vlan && (ip || ip6)))
match: \xff{6}(.{6})\1{15}
#
U 192.168.1.200:40983 -> 192.168.1.150:9 #1
  ff ff ff ff ff ff 90 2b    34 ad b5 f4 90 2b 34 ad    .......+4....+4.
  b5 f4 90 2b 34 ad b5 f4    90 2b 34 ad b5 f4 90 2b    ...+4....+4....+
  34 ad b5 f4 90 2b 34 ad    b5 f4 90 2b 34 ad b5 f4    4....+4....+4...
  90 2b 34 ad b5 f4 90 2b    34 ad b5 f4 90 2b 34 ad    .+4....+4....+4.
  b5 f4 90 2b 34 ad b5 f4    90 2b 34 ad b5 f4 90 2b    ...+4....+4....+
  34 ad b5 f4 90 2b 34 ad    b5 f4 90 2b 34 ad b5 f4    4....+4....+4...
  90 2b 34 ad b5 f4                                     .+4...          
#
```

I'm really getting stumped and need some help.  Computer is set to receive WOL packets and react to them.  It's receiving them, it's just not acting on them.  I'm starting to do some cost calculations to see if buying new components would be cheaper than just leaving the computer on.  Help please!